# YouTube embedded videos wont play in modal window in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

In Firefox, IE7, IE9 and other browsers, YouTube embedding works fine, but in IE8 nothing happens when you click the video.
I'm thinking its a CSS issue to do with Z-index perhaps? I've tried changing things around but had no luck.
Any help would be great. [Visit the page and click the images to see the problem](http://asystec.hailstormcommerce.com/?page_id=131).

Here is the CSS for the modal:

```
.youtubemodal {
width: 590px;
height: 464px;
position:fixed;
z-index:700;
top:180px;
left:50%;
display:none;
background-image: url('images/youtubeconsole.png');
margin-left:-295px;
}

.youtubediv {
position:absolute;
left:15px;
top:15px;
}

.youtubexbutton {
bottom: 12px;
right:13px;
position:absolute;
width:26px;
height:26px;
background-image:url('images/youtubex.png');
}
```

and the script:

```
jQuery('#youtube').click(function(){
jQuery('.youtubemodal').show();
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="youtubemodal"><div class="youtubediv"><iframe width="560" height="400"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/G5FRxH8ytJk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this after the `<head>` tag

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately, I also tried replacing IE7 with IE8, thanks though

Comment: still nothhing unforunately , I know embedded videos in general work no problem , it just seems to be when it pops up in its own div that it doesnt work

Comment: may be problem is you did not close '<div class="youtubemodal">'?

Comment: Hi Anton, I solved it and gave an answer below, was something silly in the end, but thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: my `youtubediv` had no width or height so I changed it to cover the size of the YouTube video.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer for future reference for others.